# What is the origins and evolutionary track of Go game?

Tags: go, history

I didn't find any source explaining the "origins" or "evolution", rather than just history of Go.

Book and article suggestions would also be helpful.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Are you talking about rules or about strategy? Both?

Comment: @havogt: Thank you for the reply. I am new to abstract gaming world, I am interested in knowing how the experiences got abstracted as the game (if it is the case) or on specifically the origins of the game. I think I should better change the title to "what is the origin and evolutionary track of Go"?

Comment: I still don't see why origin and evolution is not covered by history. My use of the word "history" is the story from the beginning (origin) until now (evolution). Maybe [senseis](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoHistory) can help you.

Comment: @havogt: I am from Physics and Math background, usually what happens in these fields is that the history covers only the chronology of the concept development rather than the evolution of the concept itself. So, in those fields there is a distinction between evolution and history, I mean the same here. Thank you again.

Comment: I thought of reading the evolutionary history of chess, then dropped it down, as I thought it to be more time efficient to read the evolutionary history of powerful Go game. I found many books on chess "history" but none on Go, even if there were any, they were not the entire history, but rather history of Go in individual countries. I didn't find any book which has a powerful general view of the Go evolutionary and origins history.

Comment: Go is so much older than chess and there is no accepted story about its origin. That's probably the reason why there is no book on the very early days of Go. You can only find some stories which are likely more [myth](http://senseis.xmp.net/?MythOfOrigin) than proper research.

Comment: @havogt: Then from your experience, which is the best move I can make now? Now I am thinking to read the evolution of earliest games itself, rather than Go or Chess. In a evolutionary way I am thinking to come for Go and Chess, to have a better idea on how games get created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41716/discussion-between-havogt-and-immortal-player).

Answer (score 2):

The following book has information on the origins and history of Go, as well as describing how to play it and explaining some strategy:

[https://www.amazon.com/More-Than-Game-Peter-Shotwell/dp/080483475X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080483475X)